# WSO2 API Manager Request Response Issue

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm able to run WSO2 API Manager without an issue. The customisations I have done is below.

[WSO2 API Manager - Displaying Private IP in the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934401/wso2-api-manager-displaying-private-ip-in-the-store)

[WSO2 API Manager - Expose Publisher & Store URLs to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914851/wso2-api-manager-expose-publisher-store-urls-to-public)

I have changed the base url and ports as given in the above answers. What I'm trying to do is, I'm exposing a REST service through the API Manager.

But the issue is when I make a request using one of the subscribers, I get below as a response.

```
<%
include("/jagg/jagg.jag");
var site = require("/site/conf/site.json");

(function () {

    jagg.render({
        "name":"page/base",
        "inputs":{
            "title":"Error",
            "body":[
                {
                    "name":"layout/base",
                    "inputs":{
                        "top":null,
                        "left":null,
                        "right":null,
                         "middle":{
                            "name":"errors",
                            "inputs":{
                                "error":"404"
                            }
                        },
                        "bottom":null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    });
}());


%>
```

What could be the issues? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is HTTP 404 error. Check the resource which you are trying is available or not.